# Using AutoMapper in .NET Core in a Library project

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

This is the solution structure:

- MyProject.WebApplication
- MyProject.Core
- MyProject.DAL

The services are located in MyProject.Core. So I want to use a mapping there between the models that come from MyProject.DAL. (`Install-Package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`)

```
return _mapper.Map<Core.Model>(DAL.model);
```

and of course vice versa.

The question is: do I need to reference the AutoMapper in both projects?

Or create a `ConfigureAutoMapper` class in MyProject.Core and call it in the startup class of `MyProject.WebApplication`?

But what about this?

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem and the best solution I have come up with for this is to define an extension method in my class library to do some initialisation only to load its assembly into memory before I call `AddAutoMapper` in my main project startup.cs:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

**Follows a wish, not a solution:**

The best way for doing this would be if calling AddAutoMapper multiple times were ok which has been unfortunately declined as per this discussion:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/issues/25

That would I would be able to load my profiles in an extension method like this:

```
 public static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddClassLibraryServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MyClassLibraryAutoMapperProfile));
    }
}
```

Currently doing so messes up with the final list of Profiles gathered at the main project.

Answer (score -1):

Since the conversion both ways will be done in your services, just wrap automapper in injected interface and you are good to go. Everything should be done in MyProject.Core.

EDIT:

As for services, it depends how you create them. In essence, you need a mapping service, so create it as any other service and inject it into classes that need mapping.

I like this pattern:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
  public MyService(IDepedencySolver ds, IRepository rep = null, IMapper mapper = null)
  { 
     _rep = rep ?? ds.GetService<IDependencySolver>();
     _mapper = mapper ?? ds.GetService<IMapper>();



    ...
   }
}
```

It allows you to inject either just service resolver, like Autofac/Splat/etc, or inject all as mocks in tests.

Some poeple like to have the default resolver as static variable, so that you avoid the first argument.

So, to answer the question of whether you need AM refernce in both projects: no, just in the MyProject.Core, where you actually use the Automapper classes.

You should wrap them in `IMapperService` or something like that. Then, in MVC, when you regiter services, you register instance of `new MapperService()` - and for that you only need reference to MyProject.Core

Comment: So don't use services.AddAutoMapper(); then? Can you give an example?

Comment: is it AutoMapper or AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection?

Comment: I haven't used the specific ASP.NET Core dependency services, and it turns out in order to use plain Automapper you can jsut follow [this](http://www.projectcodify.com/using-automapper-in-aspnet-core) tutorial, but then you need `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` dependency in your MVC project

Comment: Yes but in that tutorial everything is done in the startup project not in the Core project

Comment: Yes, you create/register instances of classes defined in MyProject.Core in Configuration part of MyProject.WebApp. If you want you use vanilla mapper, then you need to add AutoMapper nuget to both projects.